# create a column containing the baseline time for each individual

Tags: r

I have a dataset like this:

```
df=data.frame(subject= c(rep(1, 3), rep(2, 2),rep(3,4)), visit=c(1:3,1:2,1:4),time=c('2003-03-07 6:34','2003-03-07 7:33','2003-03-07 8:15','2003-03-15 6:42','2003-03-15 7:42','2003-03-16 6:20','2003-03-16 6:40','2003-03-16 7:38','2003-03-16 8:42')) 

  subject visit            time
1       1     1 2003-03-07 6:34
2       1     2 2003-03-07 7:33
3       1     3 2003-03-07 8:15
4       2     1 2003-03-15 6:42
5       2     2 2003-03-15 7:42
6       3     1 2003-03-16 6:20
7       3     2 2003-03-16 6:40
8       3     3 2003-03-16 7:38
9       3     4 2003-03-16 8:42
```

I wish to create a column so that it contains the baseline time for each individual at each visit, the expected output should look like this:

```
df1=data.frame(subject= c(rep(1, 3), rep(2, 2),rep(3,4)), visit=c(1:3,1:2,1:4),time=c('2003-03-07 6:34','2003-03-07 6:34','2003-03-07 6:34','2003-03-15 6:42','2003-03-15 6:42','2003-03-16 6:20','2003-03-16 6:20','2003-03-16 6:20','2003-03-16 6:20')) 

  subject visit            time
1       1     1 2003-03-07 6:34
2       1     2 2003-03-07 6:34
3       1     3 2003-03-07 6:34
4       2     1 2003-03-15 6:42
5       2     2 2003-03-15 6:42
6       3     1 2003-03-16 6:20
7       3     2 2003-03-16 6:20
8       3     3 2003-03-16 6:20
9       3     4 2003-03-16 6:20
```

Does anyone have any idea on how to realized this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1 (assume sort order):

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(split(df, df$subject), function(x) cbind(x,time2 = with(x, x$time[1]))))
```

Option 2 (a slightly more robust solution that figures out which is the first visit):

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(split(df, df$subject), function(x) cbind(x,time2 = with(x, x$time[which(x$visit==1)]))))
```

Option 3 (convert to POSIXct and use `min`):

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(split(df, df$subject), function(x) cbind(x,time2 = min(as.POSIXct(x$time)))))
```

Option 4 (probably fastest/easiest):

```
within(df, time2 <- ave(as.POSIXct(time), subject, FUN = min))
```

Option 5 (again assume sort order):

```
within(df, time2 <- ave(time, subject, FUN = function(x) head(x, 1)))
```

All of these will give you:

```
    subject visit            time           time2
1.1       1     1 2003-03-07 6:34 2003-03-07 6:34
1.2       1     2 2003-03-07 7:33 2003-03-07 6:34
1.3       1     3 2003-03-07 8:15 2003-03-07 6:34
2.4       2     1 2003-03-15 6:42 2003-03-15 6:42
2.5       2     2 2003-03-15 7:42 2003-03-15 6:42
3.6       3     1 2003-03-16 6:20 2003-03-16 6:20
3.7       3     2 2003-03-16 6:40 2003-03-16 6:20
3.8       3     3 2003-03-16 7:38 2003-03-16 6:20
3.9       3     4 2003-03-16 8:42 2003-03-16 6:20
```

Comment: thanks everyone for sharing these helpful solutions!

Comment: Just made some simple adjustments. No need for both `with` and `within` and no need for `list(...)` if you have only one grouping factor in `ave`.

Comment: `do.call(rbind, by(df,df$subject,FUN=function(x) within(x,time2 <- time[1])))` as `split` + `lapply` == `by`

Comment: thanks @thelatemail, if I have more than 2 grouping factors, `with`, `within` and `list (...)` should be kept, and the grouping factors should be included in `list (...)` command, right?

Answer (score 1):

`data.table` approach

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, time2 := min(as.POSIXct(time)), by = subject]
```

---

`dplyr` approach

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(subject) %>%
  mutate(time = min(as.POSIXct(time)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dplyr` for this.

```
require(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(subject) %>%
  summarize(time2 = time[1]) %>%
  left_join(df, by = "subject")
```

Here's the resulting data frame:

```
  subject           time2 visit            time
1       1 2003-03-07 6:34     1 2003-03-07 6:34
2       1 2003-03-07 6:34     2 2003-03-07 7:33
3       1 2003-03-07 6:34     3 2003-03-07 8:15
4       2 2003-03-15 6:42     1 2003-03-15 6:42
5       2 2003-03-15 6:42     2 2003-03-15 7:42
6       3 2003-03-16 6:20     1 2003-03-16 6:20
7       3 2003-03-16 6:20     2 2003-03-16 6:40
8       3 2003-03-16 6:20     3 2003-03-16 7:38
9       3 2003-03-16 6:20     4 2003-03-16 8:42
```